# zimbra server server not sync with ldap server

Tags: zimbra

Please help me out I am intermediate on linux,

1) I do have zimbra mail server on ubuntu with ladap server and external openldap server in internal location 
2) last weak we got renewed the SSL certificate on Zimbra server
3) after renewed the SSL certificate with 10 years in Zimber server its not able to sync the ladap details with internal OpenLdap server

Please help me to fix this issue

In advance thanks

Regards
Shreedhar.BH

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that all parties (Zimbra, LDAP server 1, LDAP server 2) are able to communicate with each other. Therefore all certificates should be signed by the same CA and should still be valid. You can varify this with the openssl tool.